# manage migrations when deploy rails app with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk is easy to use for deploying rails app on Amazon EC2. By set RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS as true, eb won't run the migrations itself so I can manage migrations myself.

However,SSH to the EC2 instance that created by Beanstalk, I can't find the deployed rails app in the home directory.Then I don't know where to manually rake the migrations.

I wonder why the rails app can't be found on the EC2 instance since the instance is the web server to host the app. Is it hidden somewhere? And how should I manually rake the migrations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try take a look at `/var/app/current`.

Comment: If it didn't deploy successfully it might also be in `/var/app/ondeck`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't find rake, because elastic beanstalk run ruby environment in virtual environment - rvm. Try to find in the directory /opt environment variables which set up ruby environment for current terminal. I'm not sure for ruby, but for python you should do: source /opt/python/current/env.